# Как определить текст между определенными символами?

Tags: c#

Как определить текст, находящийся между двумя определенными символами?
Например, чтобы при запуске программы пользователь ввёл:

> напиши это "привет"

И программа ему выдала:

> Вы хотели написать: привет

Хочу сделать что-нибудь наподобие такого:
 `Console.WriteLine("Вы хотели написать: %text%");`
Надеюсь нормально объяснил

Comment: Т.е что бы он не ввёл, ему выдает вы хотели ввести привет?

Comment: Нет, вот например пользователь введет:

echo("Привет") -- и программа ему выдала: "Команда выполнена. Ваше сообщение: Привет"

Comment: напиши парсер строки

Comment: Окей, а если юзер ввёл «Как дела?», то чтобы отвечало «Ну вроде норм»?

Answer (score 1):

```
Console.WriteLine("Введите команду:");
        String command = Console.ReadLine();
        int startIndex = command.IndexOf("напиши это \"");
        int finishIndrx = command.LastIndexOf("\"");
        if (startIndex >=0 && finishIndrx >=0)
        {
// 12 - это длина фразы "напиши это ""
            String reuslt = command.Substring(startIndex + 12, finishIndrx - startIndex - 12);
            Console.WriteLine("Вы хотели написать: \"{0}\"", reuslt);
        }
```